# Can pgfpages be used to scale PDF output to a specific (arbitrary) page size?

Tags: pdftex, pgfpages, magnification, resize

I have a 300-page document that has been typeset for lettersize (8.5x11 inches).  I want to create a version of it such that the PDF output is simply scaled to fit on a smaller page size (e.g. 7x10 inches) without the layout or page numbering changing at all. The original fontsize of 11pt would of course be scaled accordingly (closer to 10pt).

Originally, I thought I would have to do this by operating on the PDF file using Acrobat or another tool, but I have since learned that the LaTeX package `pgfpages` with command `\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[newsize]` might do the trick. But documentation is spotty, and examples give newsize as `a4` for example, without specifying how one might use a custom page size.

Can anyone give the magic formula, if there is one, for doing what I described at the top?  Alternatively, is there another LaTeX solution that will do the same thing?

Comment: Try out `pdfpages` (not pgfpages), it has a good documentation.

Comment: note that `pgfpages` and `pdfpages`  break hyperlink!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have figured out the answer to my own question after studying the source file for `pgfpages.sty`.  The following sample defines a new page size and gives it the name `4x6paper` , then the `resize to` command is invoked.

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\makeatletter
\define@key{pgfpagesuselayoutoption}{4x6paper}[]%                                                                                                 
{\def\pgfpageoptionheight{6in} \def\pgfpageoptionwidth{4in}}
\makeatother

\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[4x6paper]
```

Answer (score 1):

`executivepaper` has same dimensions as 7x10 inches. So :

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
    \pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[executivepaper]
```

Other existing pages sizes :

```
a0paper, a1paper, ..., a6paper;
b0paper, b1paper, ..., b6paper;
letterpaper, legalpaper;
executivepaper
```